# Product of two sequences convergence proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that a sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to a nonzero number and a sequence $\{b_n\}$ is such that $\{a_nb_n\}$ converges. Prove that $\{b_n\}$ must also converge.

Answer (score 2):

if $(a_n)$ converges $\implies \left(\dfrac{1}{a_n}\right)$converges.

we use this rule, if $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ converge then $(u_n\cdot v_n)$ converges

then $a_n\cdot b_n \cdot\dfrac{1}{a_n} = b_n\underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\ell$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: let $a_n \to A \ne 0, a_nb_n \to B$, we have: $\left|b_n - \dfrac{B}{A}\right|= \dfrac{1}{|A|}\left|Ab_n-B\right|\le \dfrac{1}{|A|}\left(\left|b_n||a_n-A| \right|+ |a_nb_n - B|\right)$. Secondly you can write: $|b_n| = \dfrac{|a_nb_n|}{|a_n|}< \dfrac{M}{\frac{|A|}{2}}= \dfrac{2M}{|A|}, n \ge N_0$. Can you finish it ?

Comment: Yes, I have it now. Thanks very much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n \to L_1 \neq 0$ then $\frac{1}{a_n} \to \frac{1}{L_1}$

From hypothesis $a_nb_n \to L_2 \in \mathbb{R}$

Thus $b_n =({a_nb_n})\frac{1}{a_n} \to L_2 \frac{1}{L_1}$